# How to the previous active Tab in ngx bootstrap tabset

Tags: angular6, ngx-bootstrap

Is there any way to know the previous active tab in tabset.
I am using ngxTabset, I need to know the previous active tab is there any way to get it

Answer (score 0):

When a tab is selected you could listen to the `(selectTab)` output. This will give you the current tab. If you store that value into a component property like `previousActiveTab` you could use the value of `this.previousActiveTab` the next time `(selectTab)` is triggered.